# Prove that the second derivative of enthalpy with respect to entropy is always positive

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Is there a way to prove that the second derivative of enthalpy with respect to entropy is always positive? If we are using the specific heat capacity at constant pressure do show how that is positive without using the above condition.

Thank you

Comment: I do not understand your question. What precisely would you like to prove, and starting from where? The constant pressure heat capacity is defined in terms of the second derivative of the enthalpy with respect to entropy.

Comment: When you say "the second derivative of enthalpy with respect to tntropy," what is being held constant?